# Eliminate extra space when using @media print {body *{visibility: hidden;}}

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a modal with a print button on it.  When someone hits that print button I'm using

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

to hide the stuff I don't want to print and then using "visibility: visible" on the things I do want printed.

It works great UNLESS someone has scrolled down some before launching the modal.  In that case, it adds the amount one has scrolled down to the top of the printed page.  Is there a way to eliminate that extra space?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hard to say without an example in action. Bust just throwing it out there, is it a case of wanting `display:none;` instead?

Comment: 'Display:none;' doesn't reserve any space for the hidden object, visibility:hidden; does.

Comment: Yes, display:none should be used on elements you don't want to show.  But if you want a page layout to look a specific way for a print, you may have to layout the page to print first, then test that.  I have had elements shift on me when I did that.  Display:none will hide all items.  Let's say you have a banner at the top of the page you want to hide on print.  Use display:none, otherwise the banner spacing will show at the top of the print.  Also, if you want to be sure, set the height and width of elements you want to hide to '0'

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media print{
   body{display:block; height:100%}
   #banner, .hideForPrint{display:none}
}
```